# @WebFilter requires ServletComponentScan

Tags: java, spring-boot

Class may be annotated with `@WebFilter(urlPatterns="*")` but spring does not run it on request. Why? If I add `@ServletComponentScan` annotation to Application class. It will work fine. Сan somehow make it work in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`@ServletComponentScan` will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `ServletComponentScan` annotation is necessary to enable scanning of Servlet components, including `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter`, and `@WebListener` in a Spring Boot application and register them with the Servlet Container.

I would prefer to use `@WebFilter` with `@ServletComponentScan`, but there is another simple way you can register your filter without XML file by using `@Component`.

```java
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    ...
}
```

If you don't have a particular URL pattern to match, you can use the `@Component` annotation to mark a class as a filter. By implementing the `OncePerRequestFilter` interface, you can ensure that the filter's `doFilter()` method is executed only once per request.